# jqGrid: c.p.colModel[e].formoptions is undefined

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, undefined

I'm trying to use **add**, **edit** and **del** functions that are included in `navGrid`.
When I try to **add** some row this error appears:

```
c.p.colModel[e].formoptions is undefined.
```

And when I try to **edit** or **del** a similar error appears.

I'm trying to use add, edit and del functions that are "included" in navGrid.
When I try to add some row this error appears: c.p.colModel[e].formoptions is undefined. 
And when I try to edit or del a similar error appears. Someone could help me to fix this?

The code of my grid is:

```
function mypricecheck(value, colname) {
    if (value < 0 || value > 20)
        return [false, "Please enter value between 0 and 20"];
    else
        return [true, ""];
}

$(function () {
    var lastSel;
    $("#list").jqGrid({
        url: "php.php",
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "POST",

        colNames: ['Index', 'ac_n_quad', 'ac_l_circ', 'ac_n_circ', 'ac_fin_g', 'ac_pot', 'ac_volt', 'ac_n_polos', 'ac_t_prot', 'ac_v_prot', 'ac_cabo', 'ac_fd', 'ac_fp', 'ac_ctr', 'ac_pot_a', 'ac_pot_b', 'ac_pot_c', 'ac_pos_1', 'ac_pos_2', 'ac_calc'],

        colModel: [
            { name: 'index', index: 'index', width: 65, key: true, hidden: true },
            { name: 'ac_n_quad', index: 'ac_n_quad', width: 110 },
            {
                name: 'ac_l_circ', index: 'ac_l_circ', width: 65, editable: true, editoptions: {
                    dataInit: function (elem) {
                        $(elem).autocomplete({
                            source: "autocomplete.php?extraparam=ac_l_circ",
                            select: function (event, ui) {
                                $(elem).val(ui.item.value);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            { name: 'ac_n_circ', index: 'ac_n_circ', width: 120, editable: true, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: mypricecheck } },
            {
                name: 'ac_fin_g', index: 'ac_fin_g', width: 75, editable: true, editoptions: {
                    dataInit: function (elem) {
                        $(elem).autocomplete({
                            source: "autocomplete.php?extraparam=ac_fin_g",
                            select: function (event, ui) {
                                $(elem).val(ui.item.value);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            { name: 'ac_pot', index: 'ac_pot', width: 55, editable: true, formatter: 'number', formatoptions: { decimalPlaces: 0, thousandsSeparator: '.' } },
            { name: 'ac_volt', index: 'ac_volt', width: 60, editable: true, edittype: "select", formatter: "select", editoptions: { value: "110:110; 220:220" } },
            { name: 'ac_n_polos', index: 'ac_n_polos', width: 100, editable: true, edittype: "select", formatter: "select", editoptions: { value: "1:1; 2:2; 3:3" } },
            { name: 'ac_t_prot', index: 'ac_t_prot', width: 100, editable: true, edittype: "select", formatter: "select", editoptions: { value: "DISJUNTOR:DISJUNTOR; FUSÍVEL:FUSÍVEL" } },
            { name: 'ac_v_prot', index: 'ac_v_prot', width: 70, editable: true },
            {
                  name: 'ac_cabo', index: 'ac_cabo', width: 60, editable: true, editoptions: {
                      dataInit: function (elem) {
                          $(elem).autocomplete({
                              source: "autocomplete.php?extraparam=ac_cabo",
                              select: function (event, ui) {
                                  $(elem).val(ui.item.value);
                              }
                          });
                      }
                  }
            },
            { name: 'ac_fd', index: 'ac_fd', width: 55, editable: true, formatter: 'number', formatoptions: { decimalPlaces: 1 } },
            { name: 'ac_fp', index: 'ac_fp', width: 55, editable: true, formatter: 'number', formatoptions: { decimalPlaces: 1 } },
            { name: 'ac_ctr', index: 'ac_ctr', width: 60 },
            { name: 'ac_pot_a', index: 'ac_pot_a', width: 70 },
            { name: 'ac_pot_b', index: 'ac_pot_b', width: 70 },
            { name: 'ac_pot_c', index: 'ac_pot_c', width: 70 },
            { name: 'ac_pos_1', index: 'ac_pos_1', width: 70 },
            { name: 'ac_pos_2', index: 'ac_pos_2', width: 70 },
            { name: 'ac_calc', index: 'ac_calc', width: 65 }
        ],
        cmTemplate: { align: "center" },
        ondblClickRow: function (id, iRow, iCol, e) {
            if (id) {
                if (id !== lastSel) {
                    $("#list").restoreRow(lastSel);
                    var cm = $("#list").jqGrid('getColProp', 'ac_ctr');
                    cm.editable = false;
                    $("#list").editRow(id, true);
                    $("input, select", e.target).focus().select();
                    cm.editable = true;
                    lastSel = id;
                } else {
                    $("#list").restoreRow(lastSel);
                    lastSel = "";
                }
            }
        },
        editurl: "edit.php",
        autowidth: "true",
        height: "auto",
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
        sortname: "ac_n_quad, ac_n_circ",
        sortorder: "asc",
        pager: '#pager',
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        caption: "Tabela circ_69"
    });

    $("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
        add: true,
        addtext: "Adicionar",
        edit: true,
        edittext: "Editar",
        del: true,
        deltext: "Excluir",
        search: false,
        refresh: false
    },
    {
        reloadAfterSubmit: true
    }, // add options
    {
        reloadAfterSubmit: true
    }, // edit options
    {
        reloadAfterSubmit: true
    } // del options
    );

    $("#list").jqGrid('gridResize');
});
```

Firebug shows that error is in 6083 line:

```
try { nm = g.p.colModel[i].formoptions.label; } catch (e) {}
```

Comment: First of all you should always use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` if you reports an error. Additionally you see typically the line of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` where the error took place. The information could be helpful too. Seconds you should includes JavaScript code which you use to create jqGrid and to call `navGrid`.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Oleg! :D I changed this.
The error is in the line `6083:  try { nm = g.p.colModel[i].formoptions.label; } catch (e) {} ` . I will include the code above!

Comment: @Oleg I included my code on the post. Do I have to do something to implement the operations? Or am I doing this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure where you can see the error "c.p.colModel[e].formoptions is undefined.". The code

```js
try { nm = g.p.colModel[i].formoptions.label; } catch (e) {}
```

do produce exception during validation of column 'ac_n_circ', but the exception will be catched (see `catch (e) {}` part). So no error message should be shown.

I agree that [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.common.js#L590) of code is not perfect, but it is still not an error. If you do want to elliminate the exception you can just add

```
formoptions: {}
```

to columns where you use `editrules`.

Comment: I don't know why, I don't know how, but the error disappears now and I didn't change anything! Wierd things happens! hahaha Now just my edit is not working! But thanks for your time and your help! :)

Comment: @mzs_newbie: You are welcome! I suppose that you executed the code in the debugger and used option "stop on exception". It's a button in the debugger which you can select.